# How to use RecycleView in Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've trying to learn Kivy and made a small project with many screens. First problem was, I've wanted to show 20 question and with a checkbox for each one. But if 20 questions fit on a screen the image won't be nice. In order to fix that
I want to use scroll. So if you can scroll down, the problem would be solved. However I can't use RecycleView in Screen.

So how can I use RecycleView in Screen?

I looked at other similar issues on the internet but either I didn't understand or wasn't what I needed.

**Edit:** The image generated by the code in my `.kv` file this is what I want. I just need to add a down scroll feature. How can I do this?

My .kv file

```
<SkillChose>:
    name:"skill"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use ScrollView to scroll your GridLayout up and down.
   Here's an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

KV = """
BoxLayout

    ScrollView:
        # uncomment the line below if items text looks a bit blurry
        #on_pos: self.pos = tuple(map(int, args[1]))

        size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y: None
            row_default_height: '50sp'
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols:2

            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"try"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"pls"
            CheckBox:
            Label:
                text:"more"
            CheckBox:
"""
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

MyApp().run()
```

2. You can use RecycleView in Screens.
   I wrote a simple example for you:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

KV = """
ScreenManager
    Screen
        name: 's1'
        BoxLayout
            Button
                text: 'go to screen 2'
                on_press: root.current = 's2'
            RV

    Screen
        name: 's2'
        BoxLayout
            Button
                text: 'go to screen 1'
                on_press: root.current = 's1'
            RV


<RV>
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
"""

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

MyApp().run()
```

But working with RecycleView is a little more difficult than with a scroll view.

And please pay attention - there is one unexpected feature when using RecycleView with Checkboxes - incorrect display of selected checkboxes when scrolling.
This is fixed by tshirtman: [here](https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/aae7cc0a18c1cfe92b4a0399d2a0e29e) and [here](https://gist.github.com/tshirtman/48aaed06d2af6bb2d7c78edf0e7efe35)

Comment: Thanks dude first one enough for me and thanks for example i saw a lot of examples but this one is great thanks a lot.